# How to deal with inexact pointcloud matching?

Tags: slam, lidar, point-cloud

When running ICP(for example with SLAM) it's possible your next position does not have a point cloud which matches up with the prior point cloud due to resolution limits. How is this dealt with it? You could artificially add points to the prior point cloud(ex, linear interpolation though I'm not sure how that works in 3d).

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean ICP, not IPC.

The most typical way is using plane features. Plane information could be extracted by voxelisation and NDT.

Plane-to-point or plane-to-plane is enough for the registration of sparse points. You don't need to do the interpolation at all.

Comment: Thanks, how would that work though? You would need to extract the planes using something like RANSAC via parameter estimation and then what?

Comment: Try to search plane-to-point ICP and NDT ICP.